# Angular [disabled] attribute failing when checking conditions

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I have this form made with Angular Material and Angular Flex-Layout and have a couple of radio buttons and a I need to enable the submit button if any of them are selected, by default no radio button is selected and the input button is disabled. But I'm passing a condition in the HTML that checks if any is selected, however only the first radio button enable the input button and I can't understand why.

This is an extract of the HTML `form` code:

// typical form code here....

```
                <!--assingn-->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="assign">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                        Asignar
                    </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                        <mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="assign">
                            <mat-radio-button [value]="
                                    !element.imei
                                        ? element.id
                                        : element.imei
                                "></mat-radio-button>
                        </mat-radio-group>
                    </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
                <!--unassign-->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="unassign">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                        Desasignar
                    </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                        <mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="unassign">
                            <mat-radio-button [value]="
                            !element.imei
                                ? element.id
                                : element.imei
                        "></mat-radio-button>
                        </mat-radio-group>
                    </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
```

//....more typical code....

and this is the input

```
<div mat-dialog-actions class="modalActions" [hidden]="!loadingTable">
    <div fxFlex fxLayoutAlign="center center">
        <button mat-icon-button color="accent" mat-raised-button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"
            matTooltip="Assign Driver" [matTooltipPosition]="'above'" [disabled]="!assign || !unassign"
            (click)="assign ? assignDriver() : unAssignDriver() ">
            <mat-icon>done</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Why the input is only disabled if I select the "assign" radio button if I set an OR operator to check "assign" or "unassign" radio buttons?

Many thanks.

Comment: can you please provide working demo on stackblitz ?

Comment: I can't :( It's a veeeeery huge project and depends on stuff in backend. It wouldn't work I think